# Is Arduino WiFi101 library fully compatible with Arduino MKR1000 with WiFi HW?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, shields, mkr1000

Will all the classes in this library work with the MKR1000 with wifi hardware?
The guide mentions "wifi shield".

So, does the library work exactly the same with the Arduino MKR100 (with the onboard wifi HW) as it does with the wifi shield?

[WiFi101 library reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi101)